# ValueError: invalid literal for int() with base 10: '' I got this error when empty value was sent

Tags: python, django

I got ValueError: `invalid literal for int() with base 10: ''` error. I wrote

```
def convert_json(request):
    json_body = json.loads(request.body)
    return json_body.get('ans', 0)
```

When I send json like

```
{ "ans": "" }
```

the error happens.I really cannot understand why this error happens because I think 0 is returned.In this json,"" means None , so 0 should be returned,I think.But my code did not work wells how should i fix this?What should I write it to make ideal system?

Comment: Can you post the traceback? I got the impression that the error is happening somewhere else

Comment: Somewhere, you're trying to convert an empty string to an `int`, and that's not valid.

Comment: Please check what the value of `request.body` is. Using the json example you provided - no errors are thrown for me. I agree with @WillemVanOnsem that this error feels like it does not happen in the code posted.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

In Python, `get()` will return the value if it exists in the dictionary, even if the value is an empty string.

You can test this by running the following code in your shell:

```
>>> json_body = {"ans": ""}  
>>> json_body.get('ans', 0)
''
```

If you want to convert empty strings to `0`, then you should do this in your `convert_json` method.

```
def convert_json(request):
    json_body = json.loads(request.body)
    ans = json_body.get('ans', 0)
    if ans == '':
        ans = 0
    return ans
```

Answer (score 0):

you can chage code to:

```
def convert_json(request):
    json_body = json.loads(request.body)
    return json_body.get('ans') and int(json_body.get('ans')) or 0
```

In upper code if `ans` type wasn't number ValeError raising.